# Smooth refresh of an html page which is showing datas from a constantly updating MySQL column

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I'm opening a new thread here for more clarity, since we solved the first problems, thanks to you guys :)

We have an AI which is constantly writing a text and pushing it into a MySQL bdd. We want to show this text as an infinite publishing thing online. We would like to see it writing, like when you're on your screen and you're writing a text so we tried this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>

<script type = "text/javascript" src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="myTable"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">  
        function page_refresh() {
            $.ajax({
                url : 'getData.php',
                type : 'GET',
                success : function(data) { 
                    $('#myTable').html(data);
                },
                error : function(request,error)
                {
                    alert("Request error : "+JSON.stringify(request));
                }
            });
        }

        var period = 100; //NOTE: period is passed in milliseconds
        setInterval(page_refresh, period); 
    </script>

</body>
```

And for getData.php

```
<?php
$dbhandle = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=writing", "root", "*********");//this connects to your mysql table
$sql = "SELECT text, id, date FROM table_02 ;"; //thise is your query, where you select what data you want from the table
$query = $dbhandle->prepare($sql); 

if ($query->execute() == FALSE)
    { die("Query error: " . implode($query->errorInfo(), ' ')); } //this is a measure to close the connection if there is an error

    echo('<table>');
        echo('<tr><th>Test</th></tr>');
        while ($row = $query->fetch()) {
            echo('<tr>');
                ##echo('<td>'.$row ['id'].'</td>');
                ##echo('<td>'.$row ['date'].'</td>');
                echo('<td>'.$row ['text'].'</td>');
            echo('</tr>');
        }
    echo('</table>');
?>
```

The

```
var period = 100; //NOTE: period is passed in milliseconds
            setInterval(page_refresh, period);
```

seems to not work well with such low timings, it look like it's just refreshing the whole page with the test datas we have. Plus, for some reasons, the page remains blank for a few seconds before showing the datas. Is there a more interesting way to do this ?

Comment: Short story is make a websocket and stream the text via the websocket from the backend to the frontend and use Javascript to update your text in the html. You don't want to re-render with a page refresh as that doesn't seem to be what you want based on your explanation.

Comment: Do you know a good tuto from where I could improve and work on this ?

Comment: Your interval period needs to be higher. Unless you're working with little amounts of data and your webservice server is running on the same machine as your database server, 100ms won't cut. Either it will fetch a lot of things and try to display them at the same time, or it will break your page layout and return a lot of timeouts/empty responses.

Comment: Your AI could not write to a database and just write to the websocket and when its done write to the database.

Comment: Use ratchet. http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world

Comment: Forgot about telling you that this question has nothing to do with ASP.NET-Ajax. I suggest you remove that tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have any knowledge of using WebSockets ? This technology was created to replace periodical polling of the server to get updates. Instead of polling from client, server can push changes to the client. You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API)

Comment: Absolutely not, I'm looking for help from friends and I'm crawling through Google to find tutorials

Answer (score 1):

As I said in my comment, 100ms won't do for your database to fetch the data for the webservice and for the webservice to relay the data to your frontend. This will only work properly if you're working with low quantities of data and if your webservice server resides on the same machine (or close to it) of your database server.

Now, for the "more interesting way of doing this".

You could fetch the data you need every 100ms, no problem, but you can't try to display it right away (I already explained why in my comment). Instead, build a queue and a function to display the first element of it. When the function returns, it's time to pop the first element off the queue and display the next one. This way you ensure that text will always be displayed correctly and in order of insertion.

Comment: The webserver and the BDD are on the same machine. 

We'll try to work on something based on your advice. Thanks !